# Updating JQuery Mobile link/href with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've hit a frustrating problem and cannot seem to locate a solution to it in conventional searches (apologies if I missed a trick).

I'm using multi-pages and am trying to update the page that a link goes to.

The code:

```
<a href="#page_${i+1}" id="theNextButton_${i}" data-role="button" rel="external">Next</a>

 $("#page_"+counter).attr("ahref", "#page_"+(data.index+1 ))
```

the counter is iterated. `data.index+1` is the number of the desired page to go. All pages are sequentially numbered with a `#page_ prefix`.

Looking inside JS Console and inspecting the link I can see that it updates the link correctly but then clicking on the link leads it to do the initial page transition.

Anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: The link you posted has the ID `theNextButton_` but you select a link with the ID `page_` in your jQuery. Seems to be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your jQuery function `.attr` has invalid attribute name `ahref`, use `href` instead.